# Is there any way for me to "stay on" (?) an iteration in a loop until a seperate condition is fulfilled?

Tags: c#

I am recreating wordle in C#, but I am having trouble with my loops/arrays. Below is my code:

```
private static void runGame()
{
    try
    {
        // Open files
        answersInFile = File.OpenText("WordleAnswers.txt");
        extrasInFile = File.OpenText("WordleExtras.txt");

        // Add words from extra file to list
        while (!extrasInFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            // Read the file and add words from the file to the list
            extrasLine = extrasInFile.ReadLine();
            extras.Add(extrasLine);
        }

        // Add words from answer file to list
        while (!answersInFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            // Read the file and add words from the file to the list
            answersLine = answersInFile.ReadLine();
            answers.Add(answersLine);
        }

        // Get a word from the answer list
        answerWord = answers[(rng.Next(0, answers.Count))];

        // Convert user word to char to display in board if word is valid
        for (int i = 0; i < userGuessChars2D.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            // Check if user guess is equal to the word
            if (userGuesses == answerWord)
            {
                // Clear screen and re-display board
                Console.Clear();
                displayBoard();

                // Inform user that they guessed the correct wordada
                Console.WriteLine("\nCongratulations. You guessed " + answerWord + ", the correct word!");
                Console.WriteLine("Click [3] + [ENTER] to view statistics");
            }

            // Clear and  re-display the board and increase guess number by 1
            Console.Clear();
            displayBoard();

            // Store user guess
            userGuesses = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            guessNum++;
            switchColour();

            for (int j = 0; j < userGuessChars2D.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (answers.Contains(userGuesses) || extras.Contains(userGuesses))
                {
                    userGuessChars2D[i, j] = userGuesses[j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnf)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + fnf.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close files
        answersInFile.Close();
        extrasInFile.Close();
    }
}
```

"answers" and "extras" are both files containing possible answer words and valid input words. If I guess a word that is not contained in either of these files, the word is not converted to char, but it still takes up a row in my array. For example, if I type two words at the start that are not in the files, the third word I enter will be stored in the third row of the array, when it should be stored in the first. Is there any way for me to "stay" on an iteration in my loop so that it doesn't increase when I enter an invalid word? Thanks

Comment: You mean to increment the loop variable only if a certain condition is fulfilled? Sure, move the increment out of the `for` to the end of the loop body and make it conditional using `if`.

Comment: `extras = File.ReadAllLines("WordleExtras.txt").ToList();` seems simpler than how you're populating your lists.

Comment: You state that, *""answers" and "extras" are both files"*, but in your code they appear to be `List<string>` objects. Can you clarify?

Comment: You say you *"convert word to char"*. Do you mean a `char[]` instead? Because a `char` is just a single character.

Answer (score 0):

You have one loop for valid & invalid answers, but you're incrementing the index each time. You can use two counters

```cs
// Declare your variables outside of the loop
var invalidCount = 0;
var validCount = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < userGuessChars2D.GetLength(1); j++)
{
    if (answers.Contains(userGuesses)
    {
        // Store the guess
        userGuessChars2d[validCount, j] = usersGuesses[j]

        // Increase the count/index for valid answers
        validCount++;
    }

    if (extras.Contains(userGuesses))
    {
        // Store the guess
        userGuessChars2D[invalidCount, j] = userGuesses[j];

        // Increase the count/index for invalid answers
        invalidCount++
    }
}
```

Since you're using a jagged array, this shouldn't overwrite any answers

Answer (score 0):

"Stay” means you need to manually control the loop process, so use *while* instead *for*.

```
var i = 0;
while (i < userGuessChars2D.GetLength(0))
{
    ...
    ...

    var bingo = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < userGuessChars2D.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        if (answers.Contains(userGuesses) || extras.Contains(userGuesses))
        {
            userGuessChars2D[i, j] = userGuesses[j];
            bingo++;
        }
    }

    if(bingo > 0)
        i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand what all your code is doing, but I think the answer to your question is to first determine if the word is valid before determining if it's correct (and then adding it to an array).

You can do this with a while loop, something like:

```
List<string> answers = File.ReadAllLines("WordleAnswers.txt").ToList();
List<string> extras = File.ReadAllLines("WordleExtras.txt").ToList();
List<string> validWords = answers.Concat(extras).ToList();

// Here, GetWordFromUser is used in place of whatever 
// mechanism you're using to get the user's input
string userWord = GetWordFromUser();

// This loop will continue forever until the user enters a valid word
while(!validWords.Contains(userWord))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Sorry, '{userWord}' is not a recognized word.");
    userWord = GetWordFromUser();
}

// At this point, userWord is a valid word and we can continue
```